# How to set DEFAULT value on existing Blob column to EMPTY_BLOB()

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, ddl

I am trying to alter a table by adding a default value for a BLOB column in an Oracle database, with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE
    MODIFY (BLOB_0 BLOB(4000) DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB())
```

But getting the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Could it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE
    MODIFY BLOB_0 DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove size(4000) of BLOB:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE
    MODIFY (BLOB_0 BLOB DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB());
```

Or just add default to table:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ALTER COLUMN BLOB_0 SET DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB()
```

Comment: I get "SQL Error: ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns" when removing the sizing...

Comment: @PeetvdWesthuizen try `ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE
ALTER COLUMN BLOB_0 SET DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB()`